# .Net Framework 3.5 Turn On Error

Tags: .net, iis

Until yesterday everything was working fine like IIS, Visual Studio 2015 enterprise. I installed DeployR server and all of a sudden IIS stopped working. I did a bit of research and as suggested started Turning On/OFF .Net Framework, IIS Services from "Windows Turn On & Off" panel. None of them got installed correctly and everytime I get error message at last. I had tried numerous times restarting my machine evrytime but still the same. I also tried .Net Framework clean up utility and tried as suggested but same result. Also tried scanning from command prompt. It ended successfully but still framework didn't get installed.

Now the Visual Studio isn't getting started giving .Net Framework error. Please adivse if there is a way out to repair this or I need to format my system.

Error:
1.) On Turning On Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5.1, I get message "An error has occurred. Not all the features were successfully changed".

2.) When I try to open Visual Studio, The error is ".Net Framework required".

3.) On trying to install .Net Framework 4.6.1, it starts and after few seconds of progress, stops saying "Installation unsuccessful".

Comment: We're not mind readers. If you're getting error messages, please include the *text* of the error message.

Comment: Apologies for not putting up the exact wording. Edited my post